# JSONDecodeError when using Pandas Datareader

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader, jsondecoder

Following [this tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/getting-stock-prices-python-programming-for-finance/), I get the error in the screenshot below when I run the command: `df = web.DataReader("TSLA", 'morningstar', start, end)`

This is the error I get. What to do?

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a copy of your copy of your full code?

Answer (score 0):

`morningstar` has been deprecated and thus has to be replaced with `yahoo`.